# How producer make sure that broker accepted his message?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

If I understand JMS correctly, the consumer sends acknowledgement to the broker, and the broker understands that the consumer accepted the message. But how does the producer make sure that broker accepted the message? I don't see any acknowledgements in the API.

Does the method send sync or async?

Answer (score 0):

> Acknowledgement is a consumer side concept. Acknowledgement is the way
>   that a consumer informs the JMS provider that it has successfully
>   received a message. On the producer side, the only notion of
>   acknowledgement consists of a successful invocation of either the
>   topic publishe’s publish method or the queue sender’s send method. If
>   an acknowledgement is given for a message it indicates that the JMS
>   provider must not deliver that same message to the consumer in
>   question again and also the JMS provider can release any resources it
>   is holding on behalf of the said message (i.e if a JMS queue is
>   considered after acknowledgement of successful delivery, that message
>   is removed from the queue). In order to minimize resource consumption,
>   consumer applications need to acknowledge messages as quickly as
>   possible after successful delivery.

source: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/jms-message-delivery-reliability-acknowledgement-patterns/

Comment: It is not full answer. **On the producer side, the only notion of acknowledgement consists of a successful invocation of either the topic publishe’s publish method or the queue sender’s send method.** I want to more about this phrase

Comment: There's nothing more - if the message is delivered (succesfully send or published) then it is delivered - that means there was no error or no exception thrown during invocation of these methods, it also means that client has received this message, from now whatever the client will do with that message is His responsibility.

Comment: Do you want to say that it is unrelated with delivery mode and persistent mode? transactions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, but JMS help with transactions in such a way that it governs that some message will be eventually delivered - this is kind of promise that is considered to be part of transaction. So it is related in the way that the client succesfull(or not) receive event is needed by the JMS to know how to act.

Comment: I consumer. I invoked send method. Is it  return immeditely or under the hood it await acknowledge from broker?

Comment: When send method is invoked successfully, it means that the consumer has received the full message succesfully - it doesn't need to confirm anything later - it has a chance to signal any error when receiving the message, after that it is considered to be received succesfully - of course there is a communication from the consumer to the sender to confirm successfull receive but it happens in a scope of this single send method. So if send or publish finish without errors, the messge was delivered succesfully, from this point it is a consumer responsibility to process it.